# Can ZFC+A and ZFC+negation of A be both inconsistent where A is some conjecture?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, incompleteness, provability

So I know that a conjecture/statement or negation of it plus ZFC can both turn out to be consistent, which means that a statement is not provable.

But I would like to go opposite way - and let's say they are both inconsistent. First of all, is this possible, and secondly, if there is an example, what would be a such case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This cannot happen, assuming ZFC itself is consistent.

If $T$ is any theory then $T+A$ is inconsistent if and only if $T$ proves $\lnot A$. Therefore, if both $T+A$ and $T+\lnot A$ are inconsistent, $T$ must have already been inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

If a theory proves $X$ and it proves $Y$, it proves $X \land Y$ (this is how $X \land Y$ is typically proven). So if it proves $A$ and $\lnot A$, it proves $A \land \lnot A$, meaning ZFC would be inconsistent.